# PHP MySQLi Prepared Statements: Can this select query be hacked/injected?

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-injection

i want to know can this be hacked/injected?

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['name']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if($result->num_rows === 0) exit('No rows');
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  //do some stuff
}
var_export($ages);
$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given an [answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/285587) suggests **almost identical code for protection**, let alone using exactly the same **principle** you can safely assume that your query is protected.

If you want to know how it works, I also wrote an answer on Stack Overflow, https://stackoverflow.com/a/8265319/285587

Nevertheless, as this site is for the code reviews offering some suggestions, I would suggest to use PDO for database interactions instead of mysqli. Simply because PDO API is much more versatile and easier to use. see your snippet rewritten in PDO:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name = ?");
$stmt->execute([$_POST['name']]);
if($stmt->rowCount() === 0) exit('No rows');
while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
  //do some stuff
}
```

as you can see some nagging operations are just gone. I wrote a [tutorial on PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo), which I would quite expectedly recommend.